# Adjoint operator and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ${e_1,e_2}$ be the standard basis in $\mathbb R^2$. Suppose $T$ is a linear mapping on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $T(e_1) = −2e_2$ and $T(e_2) = e_1 − 3e_2$. Find a basis in $\mathbb R^2$ in which the matrix of this mapping is self-adjoint.

Here is my approach:

$T(e_1) = -2 (0,1)=(0,-2)$,

$T(e_2) = (1,0) - 3(0,1) = (1,-3)$

$ T = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-2 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix} $

$ T^* =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
1 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix} $

Then, do i have find eigen vectors since they form orthonormal basis?

But here I need a basis.

Thanks!

Comment: eigenvectors do not generally form an orthonormal basis, or even a basis for that matter.  However, if $T$ has real eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then the basis of eigenvectors will answer the question.

Comment: I have eigen values and vectors then how do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T$ has the eigenvalues $-1,-2$.  It follows that a pair of eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ corresponding to $-1$ and $-2$ respectively form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$.  With respect to this basis, $T$ is given by
$$
\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-2}
$$
which is clearly self-adjoint.